# source() not recognising characters of Sys.setlocale in R

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, localization

When I'm running my source-line with `encoding = "UTF-8"`, R gives me an error message:
`INCOMPLETE_STRING`

The script stops at the first special character (ö).
Before I run the script, I defined (Windows 10 PC)

```
Sys.setlocale ("LC_ALL","German")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252"
```

Running the code manually works when I open the script with UTF-8 encoding. If I understood correctly, I cannot set the locale to UTF-8 on a Windows PC, right? What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer myself.

```
encoding = "windows-1252"
```

is the correct encoding for source, although I saved it as UTF-8. Very strange! Hope it will help someone else.